# How to use objects inside res() in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

When I tried giving like this, it says error

```
 temaplateObj.name: obj.name,
                ^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

My code:

```
 var temaplateObj = {};    
 res.render('modules/users/server/templates/getdeals', {
    temaplateObj.name: obj.name,
    temaplateObj.from: common.tokenInfo.name,
    temaplateObj.appName: 'GAIPP',
    temaplateObj.company: company,
    temaplateObj.logo: logo,
    temaplateObj.url:url
  },
```

I am not sure how to assing values to an obj inside `res({})`. Can any one suggest help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a *valid* object to `res.render()`:

```
res.render('modules/users/server/templates/getdeals', {
  name    : obj.name,
  from    : common.tokenInfo.name,
  appName : 'GAIPP',
  company : company,
  logo    : logo,
  url     : url
});
```

There's no need for `temaplateObj`.

If you want to assign it to an object first, use this:

```
var templateObj = {
  name    : obj.name,
  from    : common.tokenInfo.name,
  appName : 'GAIPP',
  company : company,
  logo    : logo,
  url     : url
};
res.render('modules/users/server/templates/getdeals', templateObj);
```

Comment: That ok but if i want to assing it to an object ,how?

Comment: Ir=ts not working when i have this caseres.render('modules/users/server/templates/invite-agent',templateObj, 
        function (err, emailHTML) {
        done(err, emailHTML);
      });
    },